# No se cambia el tamaño de letra en static text

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, jasper

Cuando pulso en vista previa en JasperReport el report se genera bien, con el tamaño de letra adecuado.
Sin embargo cuando el reporte es generado a través de mi aplicación Java, el reporte se genera bien, pero con un tamaño de letra estandar. Estoy utilizando la librería jasper-5.0.

He probado diversas cosas como generar un jar con las fuentes utilizadas, añadir la propiedad net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font con valor a true. Nada de esto me ha funcionado hasta el momento.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea más?

Comment: Hola David, veo que acabas de ingresar al sitio, te doy la bienvenida y te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento básico del 

sitio. Para realizar preguntas es importante revises [ask] que te brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la 

comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!, un gran saludo!.

Answer (score 0):

Debes compilar con jasperreports-5.2.0.jar, este debería estar con java versión 1.8.*

Para fuentes personalizadas, con `iReport`, exportar las fuentes a un archivo `.jar` y añadir este jar al classpath.

Todo esto se debe a la versión del java, ya que para `iReport` debe ejecutarse con una versión anterior al 1.8